# Localizing Google Docs form

Tags: javascript, forms, localization, google-apps-script, customization

Is there any way to localize Google Docs forms?

Where I live English is not natively spoken, therefore I would like all the information to be in another language (so that I can edit the localization on my own).

For example: There is a question type checkbox that says "Other:" and I would like to change that "Other" to something else. This is my main priority but if I could change validation messages, that would be even better!

I am not very familiar with JavaScript (I've read that people use it to change stuff in docs) but a simple replace function should do the trick. I also saw that people tend to look at forms source pages and edit it later on in Notepad and add the code to their websites, but there seems to be no way to add that edited form back to Google Docs, where I need it to collect data into a spreadsheet.

Edit: "Localizing Google Docs form" is not quite accurate. Because I'd like it to say what I want, not just translation. Although I would be satisfied with that too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google will automatically translate things like the Submit button with the following priority:

1. The language settings of the user's google account.
2. The language setting in the link they access (eg &hl=ru for russian)
3. I'm not sure what happens otherwise...

If you link to the form with the &hl=.., then if your users are registered google users #1 will apply, otherwise #2 will apply.

You can test these codes in Incognito mode in Chrome.

A full list of codes is available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes#interfacelanguage).